# Get emoji chars with Twitter4j

Tags: java, apache-kafka, twitter4j, emoji

I have been following [this guide](http://saurzcode.in/2015/02/kafka-producer-using-twitter-stream/) to create a Kafka producer with Twitter posts. Using the provided java file, I've managed to create the stream.
The problem is that the tweets don't have emojis, they have just "?" in place of them.
How can I have readable emojis?

Comment: You need to make sure that everything in your chain is using unicode encoding. You also need to make sure you're on a browser that supports the particular emojis you're using.

Comment: Actually in the code provided from the guide, unicode is never mentioned. How do I convert the strings to Unicode?